# Making Timers available for GC?

Tags: actionscript-3, timer, garbage-collection

In a function that creates a new timer every time it is called, is this the correct way to dispose of it?

```
private var _timers:Vector.<Timer> = new Vector.<Timer>;
private var _timer:Timer

private function timer():void
{
    _timer = new Timer(10000, 1);
    _timers.push(_timer);
    _timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimer, false,0,true);
    _timer.start();
}

private function onTimer(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    e.target.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimer);
    _timers[0] = null;
    _timers.shift();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can add a

```
_timers[0].stop();
```

Comment: I think this one true answer.  I believe if the timer is still running, it will have an internal reference somewhere.  The one line _timers[0] = null is unnnecessary, since you're shifting it out anyways.

Comment: He's set the running count to `1` which means it will only run once, so you don't need to call `stop()`. Just need to remove all references and the GC will take care of the rest

Answer (score 1):

I've made function "delay" that handles delay calls. I made it for my game in which I have used delay calls alot and I had to find a way to handle delays efficiently. Still AS3 guru's out there may still find more efficient ways, please let know if any.

```
public static var timer_stack:Vector.<Timer> = new Vector.<Timer>();

public static function delay(delaytime:Number, func_name:Function, repeat:Number = 1)
{
    var timer:Timer = new Timer(delaytime, repeat);
    timer_stack.push(timer);    
    timer_stack[timer_stack.length-1].addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, func_name ,false,0,true);
    timer_stack[timer_stack.length-1].addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,
                   function(e:TimerEvent){ delay_complete(e, func_name); });
    timer_stack[timer_stack.length-1].start();
}

public static function delay_complete(e, func_name:Functio):void
{
    e.target.stop();
    e.target.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, func_name);
    timer_stack[timer_stack.length-1].removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, 
                    function(){ func_name_complete(e, func_name);} );

    for(var i=0; i < timer_stack.length; i++)
    {
        if(timer_stack[i].running == true)
            trace("timer @ "+i+" is running");

        if(timer_stack[i].running == false)
        {
            timer_stack[i] = null;
            timer_stack.splice(i,1);
            trace("remove timer @ "+i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case your times change for whatever reason, it's best to deal with the object directly instead of assuming the `Timer` object is at the `0` index.

Just a small adjustment required for `onTimer()`:

```
private function onTimer(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    var timer:Timer = e.currentTarget as Timer;

    timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimer);
    _timers.splice(_timers.indexOf(timer), 1);
}
```

You don't need to set the index to `null` and it's never good practice to assume your item will be at a specified index, always make sure. In this case you make sure by using the `indexOf()` method available in the `Array` type object *(_timers)*.

Hope it helps.